# Formating long text for a textView Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, textview, format

For a few days now, my text was correctly formatted like below and appeared correctly in the textView

```
<string name="HKCurriculum">
    <b>1 - 2 Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</b>\n\n
    <b>2 - 3</b>\t\tCras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.\n
    <b>3 - 4</b> justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.\n
    <b>4 - 5</b> justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.\n
    <b>5 - 6</b>\t\tCras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.\n
    <b>a - b</b>\t\t\tCras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. \n
    <b>b - c</b>\t\tCras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.\n
    <b>y - z</b>\t\tCras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam..\n
    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCras justo odio, dapibus ac faci\n
    <i>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</i>
</string>
```

Now the texte appear unformatted :-/
I tried with replacing \n with \t but no change appear !?

What should I do to have my text again correctly formatted please ?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: I find it particularly complicated to do by hand for a very long text. Especially since the display on the xml does not follow at all. Isn't there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a example of how you want the text to look like?
Also how are you accessing the string

in my case \n\n takes the text to the next line in the code below

Sometimes android does not work well with html tags, try to remove the br and i tags

```
<string name="locus_rationale_message">We require access of your location and camera for the feature to work. \n\nLocation details will be used to verify the location that you are uploading.</string>
```